# Doubts regarding Android tutorial "hello world"

Tags: android

Following the official Android "Hello World" tutorial, two layout files are generated: `activity_main.xml` and `fragment_main.xml`. Meanwhile, a nested class `PlaceholderFragment` is generated in class `MainActivity`. Then the tutorial asked to change `fragment_main.xml` instead of `activity_main.xml`.

My first question:
Why change `fragment_main.xml` instead of `activity_main.xml`?

Second question:
How is the class `PlaceholderFragment` used? Who called it? Since the UI is designed in `fragment_main.xml`, how the UI is visualized by `MainActivity`?

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

`fragment_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks.
Deryk

Comment: Read: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I am not using fragment at all although there is a "fragment_main.xml" and a placeholder which are created automatically. That link does not say anything about my question.

Comment: With the latest SDK updates, a fragment activity is what the default blank project defaults to now. It's not been a popular change, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513

Comment: @deryk what do you call "public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment" then? Your activity use fragments and you ask why you need to make changes in fragment_main.xml, which is why I link you the official documentation for fragments so that you can understand what it is. If you read and understand that, then everything in your code will make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You don't have to name it as fragment_main but it has to be the same name used in this line:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

2- It's visualized with this lines of code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
```

And yes, you are using fragments, so you should read about it. Fragments give a lot of power to the UI management.

Comment: Very clean explanation! "PlaceholderFragment" is added to a container.  Just I still have a doubt: where and when is "onCreateView" in class "PlaceholderFragment" executed?

Comment: It's called after the onCreate of the activity. You can see the full Fragment lifecycle here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: that is actually the confusing part. "oncreate" in "MainActivity" is for activity (extended from an activity) and "oncreateview" in "PlaceholderFragment" is for fragment (extended from a fragment). How are they mingled together? where is the "oncreate" in "PlaceholderFragment"?

Comment: Fragments don't have onCreate. They have onCreateView and onActicvityCreated. Here the most important thing is that fragments will never live without an Activity. You can have activities without fragments, but not the other way. So, the Fragment is deeply tied to the Activity lifecycle. You can implement the onCreate method of the fragment if you want to, but is better to use onCreateView because it occurs after the activity has been already created.

Comment: Then if I have onCreate in both classes, which one gets executed first, the one in MainActivity or in PlaceholderFragment?

Comment: Don't know, that's why you should not use onCreate on your Fragment, or at least don't try to do something that depends on the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of some recent updates that are not all that popular(IMO). Basically what you have here is a main activity which inflates a layout that serves as a container. The PlaceHolderFragment is just an inner class which inflates the actual "Hello World" view.

I'm guessing the reason behind this change is because fragments are commonly used where reusable code is desired - you basically abstract the view(fragment) from the container(activity). But this is not required. You can achieve the same effect by copy pasting your TextView widget you have shown above into the activity_main.xml (and then deleting the fragment_main.xml and it's corresponding backing code - PlaceHolderFragment).